# Meaning of ProductLog

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have the following equation
$$\frac{2\kappa}{(k+\kappa)^2}=2i\ell e^{-2ik\ell} $$
with $\kappa, \ell \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{C}$ which I want to solve for $k$.

Using

```
Reduce[((2*κ)/(k+κ)^2)-2*x*I*Exp[-2*I*l*k]==0, k]
```

Mathematica gives me the following solution:

$(k\neq 0\land l=0\land \kappa =0)\lor \left(l\neq 0\land \kappa =-\frac{i}{l}\land k=0\right)\lor \left(c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \sqrt{-i \kappa  l e^{-2 i \kappa  l}}\neq 0\land l\neq 0\land \kappa +k\neq 0\land \left(k=\frac{-\kappa  l+i \cdot\text{ProductLog}\left[c_1,-i \sqrt{-i \kappa  l e^{-2 i \kappa  l}}\right]}{l}\lor k=\frac{-\kappa  l+i \cdot\text{ProductLog}\left[c_1,i \sqrt{-i \kappa  l e^{-2 i \kappa  l}}\right]}{l}\right)\right)$

I don't really know how to deal with the ProductLog. I looked it up and know, that ProductLog$[z]$  gives the principal solution for $w$ in $z=we^w$, which is the Lambert $W$ function. But what does this actually mean? Is there a way for me to compute without Mathematica, that this is a solution of my equation above?

Or are there maybe any better commands than "Reduce" to find solutions?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It means this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.  There is no simpler form for this function -- treat it like other named functions, sin, cos, etc.

Comment: "Is there a way for me to compute without Mathematica...?": (1) By hand, symbolically: You may assume that if `w = ProductLog[x]`, then `x == w*E^w`. (2) By computer system: Libraries/systems have it implemented, such as the NAG Library, SciPy, Matlab,... (3) Write one's own routine: The abstract of [this random google hit](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2012.07.008) is similar to [the description of Mathematica's algorithm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#2398) and comes with a [github repository](https://github.com/DarkoVeberic/LambertW)

Comment: If it is a homework problem, you should just present the equation you derived and say that it is not having a closed form solution. If you plan to use this equation for numerical calculations, insert numerical parameters and use `NSolve` or `FindRoot`. Finally, if you are interested in a mathematical approach, read wiki about the Lambert function. There is no simpler way, nor this function can be reduced to the elemental ones.

Comment: thank you for all your comments! its no homework problem, it has to do with my bachelor thesis and i have to show in any way that this equation has only a discrete set of solutions for $k$

Comment: With respect to your thesis problem, do you know about holomorphic functions?

Comment: As @MichaelE2 alludes, this seems to be more a question about the underlying math than a Mathematica question.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Assuming that the `x` in your code is actually `l` to agree with the equation image

```
eqn = ((2*κ)/(k + κ)^2) - 2*l*I*Exp[-2*I*l*k] == 0;

sol = Reduce[eqn, k]
```

[image]

Assuming that the conditions are met to produce the [`ProductLog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html) results

```
sol2 = {sol[[-1, -1]] // ToRules}
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
FullSimplify[eqn /. sol2]

(* {True, True} *)
```

Plotting the absolute value of `k` for the arbitrary integer constant set to zero:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@Abs[k /. sol2 /. C[1] -> 0], {κ, -2, 2}, {l, -2, 2},
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {κ, l, k}),
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, i would have never been able to do such a plot!